# Create an alias to a variable using variables defined in earlier section of code

Tags: python, alias, variable-assignment

Only been programming in python for about 1.5 years and this is my first time reaching out for live help. I typically comb over tons of resources until i figure out an issue myself rather than being told how to.  But this seems to have stumped me and its probably something stupidly simple. So please be gentle.

I need to create an alias to a variable defined in the first parts of my code that will be used to check the value of the original variable in an if else scenario and create a new variable that gets injected into a rtsp string later on as an On screen display message.

Employee enters a number. Example: 1 "Line 4"
then
depending on number entered, program determines what numbers should be created for the check "lines 6 through 24"
then *This is where im having problems*
program generates correct version of osd "lines 27 through 35"
then
program runs other code and injects osdmsg in it where needed.

I have all other aspects of the program correctly running but i cannot create the alias without it creating a new variable "osdcheck" with the value being the same name as the variable im wanting to alias.

Actual output

Odd Pump = 1
Even Pump = 2
pump1or2altosd
1     <---|--->     2

Desired output

Odd Pump = 1
Even Pump = 2
pump1or2altosd
2     <---|--->     1

```
pump1or2altosd = "off"
pump3or4altosd = "on"

pumpnumber = 1

if (pumpnumber % 2) == 0:
    evenpump=pumpnumber
    evenpump_str=str(pumpnumber)
    print("Even Pump =", evenpump)
    evenpump-=1
    evenpumpminus1=evenpump
    oddpump=evenpumpminus1
    oddpump_str=str(evenpumpminus1)
    print("Odd Pump =", oddpump)

else:  
    oddpump=pumpnumber
    oddpump_str=str(pumpnumber)
    print("Odd Pump =", oddpump)
    oddpump+=1
    oddpumpplus1=oddpump
    evenpump=oddpumpplus1
    evenpump_str=str(oddpumpplus1)
    print("Even Pump =", evenpump)

osdcheck='pump' + (oddpump_str) + 'or' + (evenpump_str) + 'altosd'
#osdcheck = 'pump{}or{}altosd'.format(oddpump_str, evenpump_str)
print(osdcheck)

if osdcheck == "off" :
#if 'pump{}or{}altosd'.format(oddpump_str, evenpump_str) == "off" :
    osdmsg = ((evenpump_str) + "     <---|--->     " + (oddpump_str))
else:
    osdmsg = ((oddpump_str) + "     <---|--->     " + (evenpump_str))    
print(osdmsg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Found information on using booleans in statement and it led me to testing till it worked.

I changed my variable values to `True` or `False`

then I added:
`osdcheck=eval(osdcheck)`
after
`osdcheck='pump' + (oddpump_str) + 'or' + (evenpump_str) + 'altosd'`

then changed my if else statement to check for `False` instead of "off"
works like a charm now.